# Image is duplicated while fetching the image from document directory

Tags: ios

I'm using scrollview for image loading.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Images"];


if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

NSArray *docsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath error:&error];
for (int i = 0; i < [docsArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *strPath = [docsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if([strPath containsString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_",strID]])
    {
        [imgArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",dataPath,strPath]]];
        NSLog(@"%@%@",dataPath,strPath);
    }

}
if([imgArray count]>0)
    [self showImages];
```

Comment: Can you clarify which language you are using? Is it Objective-C?

Comment: Seems Objective C to me

Comment: yes. this is a objective c code.